# Change of button text Android app

Tags: android, button, android-activity, text

I have two screens in my app, screen "a" and "b". Screen "b" has a button, that is defined by layout file. I need to change the text of the button from code. I managed to do this by using **button.setText()**, but when i change screen to "a" and back to "b" the text is being changed back to initial( to text which is specified in layout fail). I need to avoid such behavior, which means i need the changed text after changing of screen.
Thanks!

Comment: post your code of both activitys

Comment: where you place setText in oncreate() or other??

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android?rq=1

Comment: in onClick method of other button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use shared preferences to save the button text:

To set the text after starting activity (onCreate):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String buttonText = sharedPref.getString("buttonText");
if (buttonText != null) {
   button.setText(buttonText);
}
```

To save the new text:

```
button.setText(newButtonText);
sharedPref.editor.putString("buttonText", newButtonText).commit();
```